# Installing SPFX Extension on SharePoint Subsites - Error: "A different version of this App is already installed"

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, sub-site, pnp

I am trying to install a SPFX Extension on my root site and subsites. I am able to install it on my root sites with this script but then run into an error stating:

`Install-PnPApp : {"odata.error":{"code":"-2146232832, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"A different version of this App is already installed with the same version number.  You need to delete the app from the site and the site recycle bin to install this version."}}}`

Here is the script I am using to try and install on the subsites:

```
function AddApp {
    foreach ($site in $Sites) {

        Connect-SharePoint -WebUrl $site.SiteUrl -CheckForAppCredentials
        #Add-PnPSiteCollectionAppCatalog -site $site.SiteUrl

        Add-PnPApp -Path $PSScriptRoot/content-console.sppkg -Scope Tenant -Publish -Overwrite
        #Add-PnPCustomAction -Title "ContentConsole" -Name "ContentConsole" -Location "ClientSideExtension.ApplicationCustomizer" -ClientSideComponentId 02b801b8-0fd7-4098-8e88-9fbcf7c53db2 -Scope Site
    }
}

function InstallApp {
    foreach ($site in $Sites) {

        Connect-SharePoint -WebUrl $site.SiteUrl -CheckForAppCredentials

        $app = Get-PnPApp -Scope Tenant | Where-Object Title -eq "content-console-client-side-solution"
        Install-PnPApp -Identity $app.Id -Scope Tenant
        
        $subWebs = Get-PnPSubWebs -Recurse

        foreach ($web in $subWebs) {

            $subConnection = Connect-SharePoint -WebUrl $web.Url -CheckForAppCredentials
            Install-PnPApp -Identity $app.Id -Scope Tenant -Connection $subConnection
        }
    }
}

#Call the functions
AddApp
InstallApp
```

Any help as to why I am receiving this error would help! I have made sure to triple check the Recycle Bin. We also are not wanting to do a tenant wide deployment. This extension is only meant for specific sites and their subsites.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps below:

1. Delete the existing spfx app from everywhere( allsites )
2. Delete from recycle bin from everywhere( all sites)
3. Delete from 2nd level recycle bin from all site collections.
4. Upload the app and see if you get any error